# How can I make that when a team gets a specific amount of kills the player wins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The aim of the game is that there will be two teams facing each other, with a shop system at the spawn of each team. The currency of the shop will be by paying using emeralds. I want to make that each time a player gets a kill on an enemy player, the killer will receive 3 emeralds, and when one team gets 100 kills, that team wins the game.

I've already added the teams to the scoreboard, but I don't know how to make that whenever a team reaches a hundred kills the team wins, and I also don't know how to give an emerald to a player that recently killed an enemy.

Answer (score 1):

If each player has individual scores, the first step would be to add them all up into one cohesive team score. One way to do this would be to use a fake player for each team.

### Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add teamScore dummy
```

### Run whenever you want to update the scores:

```
/scoreboard players set red teamScore 0
/scoreboard players operation red teamScore += @a[team=red] enemyKills
/scoreboard players set blue teamScore 0
/scoreboard players operation blue teamScore += @a[team=blue] enemyKills
```

This will create two scores in `teamScore`. One named `red` with the combined `enemyKills` scores of everyone on the `red` team, and one named `blue` with the combined `enemyKills` scores of everyone on the `blue` team.

### To test if a team has won:

```
/scoreboard players test red teamScore 100
```

will test if the red team has won, while

```
/scoreboard players test blue teamScore 100
```

will test if the blue team has won.

Obviously, you don't have to use `red` and `blue` for the team names, and you could do this for more teams if necessary. And you don't need to use `enemyKills` for your scoreboard objective, the names were just arbitrarily chosen and could be any valid name.

Hope this helps! If you find anything unclear, just comment below.